Placing object at mouse position has offset
I'm using ThreeJS with MindAR, and I'm trying to put an object in the place where I clicked with my mouse.
const mousePositionX = (e.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
const mousePositionY = -(e.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
const mouse = new THREE.Vector2(mousePositionX, mousePositionY);

const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
if (intersects.length === 0) return;

topping = obj1.clone();
topping.position.set(mouse.x, mouse.y, 0.25);

There also other codes related to adding this object to the group of anchor (AR term), etc.
The result is shown below. In both pictures, I'm clicking on the very bottom of the pizza dough.
when you look at the object from top view, it places the topping (object) at the exact location of mouse click:

But when you look at it from angle, it places the topping with some offset:


Most likely, the mouse coordinates are not in the same space as the scene coordinates (this will be especially noticeable when rotating the camera), which does not translate correctly to the 3D world. Try retrieve the intersection point from the raycaster result using intersects[0].point to get accurate 3D coordinates.
Try something like this:
const mousePositionX = (e.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
const mousePositionY = -(e.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
const mouse = new THREE.Vector2(mousePositionX, mousePositionY);

const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);

if (intersects.length === 0) return;

const intersectionPoint = intersects[0].point;

const topping = obj1.clone();
topping.position.copy(intersectionPoint);

topping.position.z += 0.25;

scene.add(topping);

But if it still doesn't work, because maybe there's something wrong with the rest of the code, try taking a look at this example, maybe it will help:


<script type="importmap">
  {
"imports": {
  "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.166.0/build/three.module.js",
  "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.166.0/examples/jsm/"
}
  }
</script>

<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        const pizzaShape = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10);
        const pizzaDough = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
        const plane = new THREE.Mesh(pizzaShape, pizzaDough);
        plane.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
        scene.add(plane);

        camera.position.set(0, 10, 15); 

        const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        controls.enableDamping = true;
  
        function createIngredient() {
            const pepperoniSize = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 32, 32);
            const pepperoniType = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
            const pepperoni = new THREE.Mesh(pepperoniSize, pepperoniType);
            return pepperoni;
        }
        window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
            mouse.x = (e.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
            mouse.y = - (e.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

            const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
            raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

            const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);

            if (intersects.length > 0) {
                const intersectionPoint = intersects[0].point;
                const ingredient = createIngredient();
                ingredient.position.copy(intersectionPoint);
                scene.add(ingredient);
            }
        });

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            controls.update();
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

        animate();

        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        });

</script>




When I try point approach, it places nothing, perhaps because it has much bigger offset. mouse position log: (0.30, -0.08), point position log: (195.57, -70.90, -2085.63). I'm assuming the problem is with AR library. I just don't know how it detects I've clicked on the object, but the detected point is way off.

@Amir Is possible to make CodePen or Sandbox?

@Łukasz-d-mastalerz codepen: https://codepen.io/below231/pen/ZEdJJWP - you need camera access, then with your phone, go to https://hiukim.github.io/mind-ar-js-doc/examples/basic#try-it-out , and hold your phone with the blue picture in the link, in front of your webcam in my codepen.

I played around with it a bit, but couldn't figure anything out. The problem is most likely in AR because Raycaster seems to work well. I've never worked with such an implementation, but it seems to me that you need to search the AR documentation regarding default parameters, like you wrote.

I appreciate your help

The solution was about "world position" and "local position". I needed to convert intersectionPoint position (which is a world position) to local position (the .position which we set on pepperoni), and use the object that I was appending the pepperonis to, as the object to calculate the local position relative to. "Discover three.js" online book, chapter "Transformations" really helped me on this.

@Amir I'm glad of that. Yeah, Discover three.js is great source.
